# Select the top N exclusive values of a group in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in SQL (preferably SQL Server) to select the top N records in a group that are exclusive of the other groups?

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DISTANCE

CREATE TABLE #DISTANCE
(
    GNAME VARCHAR(3)
,   CNAME VARCHAR(3)
,   DIST NUMERIC(5,3)
)

INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
VALUES ('E1', 'C1', 1), ('E1','C2',2),
       ('E2', 'C1', 1.5), ('E2','C2',2.5)
```

If I was looking for the first exclusive CNAME for each ENAME by distance ASC, I would expect an output like this:

| Ename | Cname | Dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | C1 | 1 |
| E2 | C2 | 2.5 |

Note that E1|C2 and E2|C1 are omitted because they would be the 2nd value in a rank result for the group.

I have come up with a few SQL methods to try and pull this correctly, but my work breaks down when I add additional groups on ENAME and if I change my Top N value.

If I add to the complexity:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #DISTNACE

INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
VALUES ('E1', 'C1', 1), ('E1', 'C2', 2), 
       ('E1', 'C3', 3), ('E1', 'C4', 5),
       ('E2', 'C1', 2.5), ('E2', 'C2', 4), 
       ('E2', 'C3', 3.5), ('E2', 'C4', 6),
       ('E3', 'C4', 7), ('E3', 'C5', 6), 
       ('E3', 'C6', 4)
```

The SQL output I am trying to get to would look like this:

| GNAME | CNAME | DIST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | C1 | 1.000 |
| E1 | C2 | 2.000 |
| E1 | C3 | 3.000 |
| E2 | C4 | 6.000 |
| E3 | C6 | 4.000 |
| E3 | C5 | 6.000 |

I am able to get it to work in this particular instance, with this code:

```
WITH X AS  
(
    SELECT * 
    --, RNK             = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DIST ASC) 
    , CNAME_RNK_BY_DIST = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST ASC)
    , CNAME_RNK_BY_DIST = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST ASC) 
    FROM #DISTANCE
    )
,MINDIST AS ( -- FIRST OCCURANCE OF CNAME VALUE
    SELECT 
        CNAME
    ,   MIN(DIST) MINDIST
    FROM X GROUP BY CNAME
)
            -- SELECT * , CALC = SUM(CNAME_RNK_BY_DIST / 4) OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST ASC) FROM X order by CNAME, DIST
, X2 AS (

    SELECT *, CALC = SUM(FLOOR(CNAME_RNK_BY_DIST / 4)) OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST ASC) FROM X
)
    --SELECT * FROM X2 order by CNAME, dist
, CALC AS (
    SELECT CNAME, MAXINC = MAX(CALC) FROM X2 GROUP BY CNAME
)
    --SELECT * FROM CALC
, FIRST_OCCURANCE_PAIRS AS (
    SELECT A.*
        ,OCCURANCE = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST)
    FROM X A
    JOIN MINDIST B ON A.CNAME = B.CNAME AND A.DIST = B.MINDIST
)
    --SELECT * FROM FIRST_OCCURANCE_PAIRS

,ISO AS 
(
    SELECT * fROM FIRST_OCCURANCE_PAIRS WHERE OCCURANCE > 3 
)
--select * from FIRST_OCCURANCE_PAIRS
--  SELECT * FROM ISO
, NEXT_OCCURANCE AS (
    SELECT A.*
    FROM  X AS A
    JOIN CALC ON A.CNAME = CALC.CNAME
    JOIN ISO B ON A.CNAME_RNK_BY_DIST  =  CALC.MAXINC               and A.CNAME = B.CNAME
)
    --select * from NEXT_OCCURANCE
, FRAME AS (

SELECT 
    CNAME
,   CNAME
,   DIST

FROM FIRST_OCCURANCE_PAIRS
--WHERE OCCURANCE <=3
UNION
SELECT
    CNAME
,   CNAME
,   DIST
FROM NEXT_OCCURANCE
)
--select * from FRAME
, FINAL AS (
    SELECT * ,FINALRNK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CNAME ORDER BY DIST)
    FROM
    FRAME
)
    SELECT * FROM FINAL WHERE FINALRNK <4
```

but the logic fails as more records are added. Is there a way to clean up this SQL and achieve the results for any number of combinations?

Comment: It seems you want the row with the least `dist` per `cname`. If this is the case, then your first example is wrong. You'd want `('E1','C2',2)` in your results for C2,, not `('E2','C2',2.5)`, because 2 < 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the row with the least `dist` per `cname`. That is simply:

```
select gname, cname, dist
from
(
  select
    gname, cname, dist, rank() over (partition by cname order by dist) as rnk
  from mytable
)as r
where rnk = 1;
```

I am using `RANK` here in order to deal with ties. So, when there are two rows with the same minimum `dist` for a `cname`, you'll get those two rows for one `cname`. If you want to allow only one row per `cname`, you must use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK`, but then you must also decide which of the tying `gname` to display.

Comment: he also wants to make sure that the cname does not repeat for other groups

Comment: @Venkataraman R: I don't understand how this is supposed to be an additional rule. If we select the row with the least `dist` per `cname`, we ge each `cname` once - well, at least as long as there are no ties. I am using `RANK` in order to deal with ties. If the OP rather wants to pick only one row in that case, they can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead. Is this what you mean? But what would be the rule then for picking a row exactly? What are the "other groups" you mention?

Comment: From OP, I understand this way. For eg., (E1, C1) is one combination then, C1 should not come ever in the result set. It will be (E2, C2).

Comment: Venkataraman, your understanding is correct. In the example, C1 should not repeat in the other  G-groups.

Comment: @mdiprima: C1 will not appear twice with my query unless you have a tie. I mentioned this. If C1 has two rows `('E1', 'C1', 1)` and `('E2', 'C1', 1)`, then both will be shown. If you don't want this, then which gname do you want to show? You can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK` which I also mentioned, but then you must decide for a rule for picking the gname in case of a tie.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In the 2nd example, I am looking for the top 3 exclusive values for each GNAME. Note that for E2, it has 1 result of C4, even though it is the 2nd item when looking at CNAME by distance ASC (the first item belonging to E1). It is not grouped with E1 because it would be the 4th item in a rank (partitioned by GNAME and ordered by CNAME). I don't think your query achieves this

Comment: You are right, for C4 my query gets `('E1', 'C4', 5)`, while you seem to want `('E2', 'C4', 6)`. I don't understand why you want it, though. You are suddenly talking about the top 3 per `cname` and your query shows the top 3 for E1, it doesn't show the top 3 for E2 and E3, though. So while "top 3" is a new rule, there still must be yet some other rule that I have not understood.

Comment: I think I am able to solve my solution with this code below (although Its not exactly as I envisioned it).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my problem some more, I don't think I provided enough information to my question to be useful. After some adjustments, I think I am able to achieve what I want. Instead of being able to do this in a single query, I think I have to run a batch execution step to pass over my data to pull what I need. Perhaps there is a way for me to reduce/optimize this code below?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DISTANCE
CREATE TABLE #DISTANCE
(
    GNAME       VARCHAR(3)
,   CNAME       VARCHAR(3)
,   DIST        NUMERIC(5,3)
)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RESULT
CREATE TABLE #RESULT
(
    GNAME       VARCHAR(3)
,   CNAME       VARCHAR(3)
,   DIST        NUMERIC(5,3)
--, FINRNK      INT
)
--INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
--VALUES 
--  ('E1', 'C1', 1  )       
--, ('E1', 'C2', 2  )
--, ('E1', 'C3', 3  )
--, ('E1', 'C4', 5  )
--, ('E2', 'C1', 2.5)   
--, ('E2', 'C2', 4  )
--, ('E2', 'C3', 3.5)
--, ('E2', 'C4', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C4', 7  )       
--, ('E3', 'C5', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C6', 4  )
---- CONCLUSIONG; SCENARIO WORKS, VALUES SHIFT.


--INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
--VALUES 
--  ('E1', 'C1', 1  )       
--, ('E1', 'C2', 2  )
--, ('E1', 'C3', 3  )
--, ('E1', 'C4', 5  )
--, ('E2', 'C7', 2.5)   
--, ('E2', 'C8', 4  )
--, ('E2', 'C9', 3.5)
--, ('E2', 'C4', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C4', 7  )       
--, ('E3', 'C5', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C6', 4  )
----,   ('E3', 'C3', 1  )
-- CONCLUSIONG; SCENARIO WORKS, VALUES SHIF

INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
VALUES 
    ('E1', 'C1', 1  )       
,   ('E1', 'C2', 2  )
,   ('E1', 'C3', 3  )
,   ('E1', 'C4', 4  ) -- switch with E2 dist to switch groups in results
,   ('E2', 'C1', 2.5)   
,   ('E2', 'C2', 4  )
,   ('E2', 'C3', 3.5)
,   ('E2', 'C4', 6  ) -- switch dist with e1 to move groups in results
,   ('E3', 'C4', 7  )       
,   ('E3', 'C5', 6  )
,   ('E3', 'C6', 4  )
,   ('E3', 'C3', 1  )

--INSERT INTO #DISTANCE
--VALUES 
--  ('E1', 'C1', 1  )       
--, ('E1', 'C2', 2  )
--, ('E1', 'C3', 3  )
--, ('E1', 'C4', 5  )
--, ('E2', 'C7', 2.5)   -- CHANGE CVAL TO UNIQUE TO PULL THROUGH    
--, ('E2', 'C8', 4  )   -- CHANGE CVAL TO UNIQUE TO PULL THROUGH
--, ('E2', 'C11', 3.5)  -- CHANGE CVAL TO UNIQUE TO PULL THROUGH
--, ('E2', 'C4', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C9', 3  ) -- NEW
--, ('E3', 'C4', 7  )       
--, ('E3', 'C5', 6  )
--, ('E3', 'C6', 4  )
-- SCENARIO CORRECT. C4 SHOULD NOT BE PULLED IN.
GO

BEGIN
    ;
    WITH 
     NOROOM AS (
        SELECT GNAME FROM #RESULT GROUP BY GNAME HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3 -- HAS TO BE NOROOM BECAUSE 'HASROOM' WOULD not make sense in first pass.
    )
    ,X AS (
        SELECT 
            A.CNAME
        ,   A.DIST
        ,   A.GNAME
        ,   RNK = RANK()        OVER (PARTITION BY A.GNAME ORDER BY A.DIST ASC)
        ,   RNK2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.DIST ASC)
        ,   #RESULT.CNAME AS RSLT
        FROM #DISTANCE A
        LEFT JOIN #RESULT ON A.CNAME = #RESULT.CNAME
        LEFT JOIN NOROOM ON A.GNAME = NOROOM.GNAME
        WHERE NOROOM.GNAME IS NULL AND #RESULT.CNAME IS NULL --ORDER BY RNK
        )
        --SELECT * FROM X
    , Y AS (
        SELECT X.CNAME, MINRNK2 = MIN(X.RNK2) 
        FROM X 
        --LEFT JOIN #RESULT B ON X.CNAME = B.CNAME
        GROUP BY  X.CNAME
    )
    --  select * from y
    --  SELECT * FROM x JOIN Y ON X.CNAME = Y.CNAME AND X.RNK2 = Y.MINRNK2
    INSERT INTO #RESULT
    SELECT X.GNAME, X.CNAME, X.DIST FROM X 
     JOIN Y AS SQ ON X.CNAME = SQ.CNAME AND X.RNK2 = SQ.MINRNK2
    WHERE X.RNK <=3 --AND   #RESULT.GNAME IS NULL

     PRINT 'LOOP'
END
GO 10
     SELECT * FROM #RESULT ORDER BY GNAME
```